# Linux Environment Variables in sudo

Tags: bash, python, python3, environment-variables, django

I have an AWS ec2 instance running and have hosted a DJango based web app on it. But the problem is I cannot access the environment variables in `sudo` mode. So while my DJango app's settings file tries to access the environment variables for database credentials it is unable to do so although I can access the environment varibales without using `sudo`. Please guide me out as to how to set environment variables globally so that it can be accessed even when using the `sudo` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the -E command with sudo to keep your environment variables

> -E' The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

However if sudo means that you are running Django under root I would urge you to reconsider since this provide a major security risk. If for some reason your application is compromised then it would be possible to the attacker to run commands at the user running Django. If that user is root the attacker has full control of the system. The best practice is to have a dedicated user for your application.

If you do use a dedicated user for the application I recommend putting then environment variables in a file that application user has access to. Though I would not recommend putting plain text passwords in this either. Store them somewhere encrypted.

source:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20238

https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo